# Prove a problem that is NP-hard and not NP-complete in not in P

Tags: np, np-complete, np-hard

If A is not NP-hard, but not NP-complete, then prove that A in not in P.

A is NP-hard if there is an NP-complete problem B such that B is reducible to A in polynomial time.  A is NP-complete if A is in NP and all NP problems are reducible to A in polynomial time. But A is not NP-complete, so one one or both of those conditions must be false.  If A is not in NP, then A is not in P.  The other case is that there exists at least one NP problem that is not reducible to A in polynomial time.  This is where I am stuck. How do I get from knowing that there is an NP-complete problem that is reducible and an NP problem that is not reducible to A is not in P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a problem A is NP-hard, then all NP problems are reducible to A in polynomial time.

Proof:
Since the problem A is not NP-Complete, then there exists problem B as defined above.  All problems C in NP can be reduced to B in polynomial time, then B can be reduced to A in polynomial time.  Composition of polynomial time algorithms is polynomial, so C can be reduced to A in polynomial time.

--

Since A is NP-Hard but not NP-Complete, A must not be in NP, therefore A is not in P either.